# Heroku Node js - persistence of local variables

Tags: node.js, heroku

I know the best way to do this is to use a database. However, if I do use local variables in my back end - does anybody know if Heroku keeps the same process for all connections? Does it reset the server randomly? I only have one dyno running for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Node keeps the same process for all requests.
You can achieve this thing by creating file named **constants.js**
and I am giving example here that I want to save some object like below which should be accessible in whole code of node for all requests served by node.

```
const weekdays = {
  Monday = 1
  Monday = 2
}

const env = 'development';

module.exports = { weekdays, env }
```

To access these variables in any file you can use

```
const cst = require('constants.js');
console.log(cst.weekdays); // it will log object
console.log(cst.env); // it will log string value
```

Comment: So if they are changed every user would be able to see the changed variable?